# Aws Json Exception - A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services

I am facing an error with json , although

```
System.out.println((int)text.trim().charAt(0));
```

returns 123 which means it does starts with curly bracket.
I am totally out of ideas and i also tried to `trim()` instead of `toString()`.

```
InputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
byte[] unPackedBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
String text = new String(unPackedBytes, "UTF-8");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text.toString());
```

It is so weird because when i input the json it doesn't give any errors but when i give the compressed file it does gives errors but the output of the compressed file is exactly same with json, so i am confused.
This is the Json.

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "providerId": 123,
    "externalTrackId": "068d",
    "genres": [
        {
            "genre": "Rap/Hip-Hop",
            "subGenre": "Rap/Hip-Hop"
        }
    ],
    "title": {
        "title": "The "
    },
    "artists": [
        {
            "name": {
                "primary": {
                    "value": "J-"
                }
            },
            "role": "Artist"
        }
    ],
    "contributors": [],
    "release": {
        "id": 123,
        "title": {
            "title": "The "
        },
        "artist": {
            "primary": {
                "value": "J"
            }
        },
        "externalId": "gener2cec9477d",
        "genre": {
            "genre": "Rap/Hip-Hop",
            "subGenre": "Rap/Hip-Hop"
        },
        "copyrightYear": 0
    },
    "trackCountInMedia": 0,
    "mediaCountInRelease": 0,
    "signature": {
        "url": "https:",
        "id": 123,
        "type": "FULL",
        "audioType": "MUSIC",
        "creation": "2013-"
    },
    "label": "Unknown",
    "lastMod": "2013-01-04T16:02:57.607Z"
}
```

Cheers

Comment: What is 'text' in above code?

Comment: text is coming from inputstream because i am decompressing the file first.

Comment: Please give some text for example for the 'text' from the stream as you said, so that error can be identified.

Comment: I did and still i am facing the same problem.

Comment: Actually,  i have just found out that i am having this error while i am trying to give compressed data.

Comment: So you are getting error in this line in your code : JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text.toString()); ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer , it was a mistake of me because i wasn't decoding data from Base64.
It's weird because it was seemed like exactly same output but it wasn't.

Thanks to @Jhanvi for trying to help me.